# How to Restore MS Access database zip file in C# winForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, zip, database-restore

I have this backup and restore code in C# using MS Access as its database. I finished doing the backup in zip format and now I want to restore the Zipped file. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public void BackupDatabase(string dateToday)
    {

        string dbFileName = "dbCPS.accdb";
            string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory , dbFileName);
            string backTimeStamp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dbFileName) + "_" + dateToday + ".zip";// +Path.GetExtension(dbFileName);
            string destFileName = backTimeStamp;// +dbFileName;
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string PathtobackUp = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();
                destFileName = Path.Combine(PathtobackUp, destFileName);

                //File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, destFileName, true);
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddFile(dbFileName);
                    zip.Save(destFileName);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Backup successful! ");                  
            }            
    }

private void backupToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        BackupDatabase(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy_HH.mm"));
    }


public void RestoreDatabase(string restoreFile)
    {
        string dbFileName = "dbCPS.accdb";
        string pathBackup = restoreFile;
        string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, dbFileName);
        File.Copy(pathBackup, CurrentDatabasePath, true);
        MessageBox.Show("Restore successful! "); 
    }

private void restoreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            openFileDialogBackUp.FileName = "dbCPS";
            openFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
            if (openFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                RestoreDatabase(openFileDialogBackUp.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This code extracts the zipped file but I dont know how to do the restore at the same time.

```
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(restoreFile))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(@"C:\Users\Desktop\backup");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723.aspx), you should be able to extract the zip file directly to the destination folder. Your existing "restore" code simply does a file copy to `CurrentDatabasePath`, so one would expect that a statement like...

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(pathToZipFile, CurrentDatabasePath);
```

...would be all it takes. (I would test it myself, but `ZipFile` was apparently added in .NET 4.5 and my copy of Visual Studio is too old.)

Comment: I will replace this code?
              File.Copy(pathBackup, CurrentDatabasePath, true);

Comment: @ViFer Something like that, yes. Instead of copying a file into the `CurrentDatabasePath` you would be extracting the contents of a zip file into that location.

Comment: and then it will overwrite the existing database?

Comment: @ViFer I would assume so, but the only way to know for sure would be to test it. (Like I said, my version of Visual Studio is too old to support that feature in `System.IO.Compression`.)